# Guess my password! (Code Golf)

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

So, like the title says, today you are going to guess my password (sort of). You need to make a big long list of every possible password I might be using on my 4 digit online vault.

**Specifications:**

- It could contain any 26 letters of the alphabet in UPPER CASE.
- It could contain any numbers 0-9.
- So, basically, each digit has 36 different possibilities.
- There are four digits.
- Repeat characters are allowed! (Hint: Sample space is 1,679,616 or
  36^4)

**Program Requirements/Rules:**

- Program must output all possible answers to a text file or to the console, line by line. (One answer per line)
- You may not make use of any premade tools for this (Idk if any exist, but just in case)
- It must generate all 36^4 possible answers

Remember, this is a Code-golf. So shortest answer in bytes wins. Please use the standard title format of `##Language Name, Byte Size`. Even if there is a winner, feel free to post your answer. (It's always fun to see the different solutions in different languages).

**Edit:** *Not a duplicate of sugested, mines has different context, and different paremeters. (I require numbers, duplicate characters, and only UPPERCASE)*

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be closed as a duplicate of that question; it requires digits as well as letters, so answers can't just be copied over. Then again, it is pretty similar...

Comment: @ETHproductions yeah, IDK. I think its sort of different. I mean, the practice/methods to solve are similar/same but then the application is different.

Comment: Both questions are "Count in base B" for some B. There may be superficial differences, but they're fundamentally the same question.

Comment: If it didn't have the word "*password*" in it, there is now way it could be thought of as a copy of that question. Answer to this question in Perl 6 `.say for [X~] (0..35)».base(36)xx 4`, answer to the other question is `say 'a'.../password/` ( or `print "$_ " for 'a'.../password/` if you want it to start printing immediately. ) There is no easy way to answer either question starting out with the answer for the other one. I say remove all mention of the word *password*, and try to re-open.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills thank you. Thats what I'm trying to say here...

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills you think I should re open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth - 8 bytes

```
^+jkUTG4
```

[Try smaller password length online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%5E%2BjkUTG2&debug=0).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, the output I got when I ran your program is in pairs of two? I said the password is 4 digit.

Comment: @AshwinGupta yes, because the online interpreter would reject a program with 36^4 permutations.

Comment: Ah wait nevermind, I see, you changed the 4 to 2 for running purposes. Sorry my bad.

Comment: I'm afraid to upvote when your score is `7 777` :)

Comment: You are currently the winner unless someone can beat you. Where are the Japt and Seriously guys? They both are short-syntax golfing languages with a chance.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Sadly, the best Japt answer I can come up with is 22 bytes: `36p4 o £'0³+Xs36 u)t-4` (to try this at home, change `36p4` to `36p2`)

Comment: @ETHproductions ok, still a great answer! I love seeing these tiny golf language responses. It makes me really want to learn one. I think I might try and learn some Pyth. (I know a bit of python already so it might help). Im glad I only made you guys do 4 digits though. I was initially considering 8 digits with lower and upper case. Luckily, I thought against it because of the sheer amount of answers (62^8 = 218,340,105,584,896 or 218 trillion answers. **YIKES!**)

Comment: @Ashwin Yeah, the code actually finishes in ~45 seconds on my browser, as opposed to the 2.5 years it would take to do 8 digits ;)

Comment: @ETHproductions LOL. What? You don't want to leave your pc on for 2.5 years to run a golf program? (jk)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 38 Bytes

```
mapM(\a->['A'..'Z']++['0'..'9'])"abcd"
```

yeah, it's not gonna beat Pyth. Oh well...

Comment: Don't worry, not much beats Pyth. from what little I've seen here on CodeGolf SE in the last week or so. Still a great answer.

Comment: :p too true... I'll take beating another non-golf language for now...

Comment: Well, you beat Ruby! @quartata although it was close. 15 Bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>64</s> 53 bytes

```
[*'A'..'Z',*'0'..'9'].repeated_permutation(4){|a|p a}
```

Probably golfable further, I'm not that good at Ruby.